# How to rename the phpexcel sheet containing a chart in it?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have tried a slight variation of [**this**](https://github.com/affinitybridge/phpexcel/blob/master/Tests/33chartcreate-bar.php) example from the github page of phpexcel.
But i noticed that when i rename the excel sheet that is generated, i don't get the chart well in the sheet, as shown in the image. Not sure where i am going wrong.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->setTitle('Performance'); // Chart Fails !
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('', '', '', '', '', '', 'ClassA', 'ClassB'),
        array('', '', '', '', '', 'June',   81,   90),
        array('', '', '', '', '', 'July',   92,   91),
        array('', '', '', '', '', 'August', 81,   90),
    )
);
//  Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
$dataseriesLabels = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$G$1', null, 1),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$H$1', null, 1)
);
//  Set the X-Axis Labels
$xAxisTickValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$F$2:$F$4', null, 3),
);
//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
$dataSeriesValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$G$2:$G$4', null, 3),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$H$2:$H$4', null, 3),
);
//  Build the dataseries
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
);
//  Set additional dataseries parameters
//      Make it a horizontal bar rather than a vertical column graph
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($series));
//  Set the chart legend
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Performance');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Percentage');
//  Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotarea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    null,           // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
);
//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A2');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('E15');
//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);
// Save Excel 2007 file

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="performance.xlsx"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entries like

```
'Worksheet!$G$1'
```

are standard MS Excel range references..... the "bit" before the `!` is the Worksheet name, while the `$G$1` is the cell or cell range in that worksheet.... so if your worksheet is called `Performance` then it should read

```
'Performance!$G$1'
```

**EDIT**

If a Worksheet name in a range contains any "special" characters such as spaces, then MS Excel rules is that the worksheet name must be quoted with single quotes, so:

```
'Worksheet 1!$G$1
```

meaning that you either need to wrap your string in double quotes (escaping the `$` signs to prevent PHP attempting to interpret `$G` and `$1` as variables)

```
"'Worksheet 1'!\$G\$1"
```

or escape the single quotes

```
'\'Worksheet 1\'!$G$1'
```

(standard PHP string handling for strings containing special characters)

Comment: Worked well if the worksheet name does not contain a space, so i used underscore... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mark, this fixed the issue with spaces in sheet name.